# Android Test case coverage

Tags: android

What is the effective tool for measuring unit test case coverage in Android like test case coverage tool in IOS Xcode 7?

I am looking for something which can be executed in Android studio.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to achieve a test case with your android application? if yes what kind? Do you want to test algorithms in your code (back-end) or the UI (front-end)?